# Troubles connecting to remote instance via chrome remote desktop

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop

I am having an annoying problem - I have an instance on google cloud to which I was able to connect via chrome remote desktop, but now suddenly I can no longer connect to it (the instance is online though, as I can login into it via ssh).

This is the error message that I get when I try to copy the command from chrome remote desktop into the instance, in order to connect to it:

```
DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/0Adeu5BVo8L8UtMrMKqH-yzDXxKrjRZM_t19rL4HstNUjGX5GrgGt2jRyi9s89y7miQylrw" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
Enter a PIN of at least six digits: 
Enter the same PIN again: 
[0831/163856.832868:INFO:host_stopper.cc(37)] Stopping existing host: eb1d2e4e-45da-44ae-bb8e-5353ec49b8cf. This may take a few seconds.
[0831/163856.927379:ERROR:service_client.cc(131)] Received error code: 5, message: Requested entity was not found.
[0831/163857.018110:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(97)] The daemon is not currently running

[0831/163857.879876:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(97)]
```

This is the output of systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop.service:

```
chrome-remote-desktop.service - LSB: Chrome Remote Desktop service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/chrome-remote-desktop; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2023-08-31 16:38:22 UTC; 3min 47s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/chrome-remote-desktop.service

Aug 31 16:38:22 instance-3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Chrome Remote Desktop service...
Aug 31 16:38:22 instance-3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Chrome Remote Desktop service.
```

Not sure where the problem is, as until yesterday it was working fine - but this has happened after a reboot of the machine. I tried already apt purge chrome-remote-desktop and reinstalling chrome-remote-desktop, and I also tried the procedure at [this link](https://en.linuxportal.info/tutorials/troubleshooting/how-can-we-manually-unmask-services-that-are-masked-service-is-masked-that-we-cannot-unmask-with-the-unmask-option-of-the-systemctl-command) as at some point I was getting the same error (Unit chrome-remote-desktop.service is masked.), but nothing changes - I am still getting the error above and can no longer connect via remote desktop.

Any help would be very appreciated, as I tried already everything that I could find. Thank you!